# Python Pandas Cumulative Multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a small dataframe and I want to multiply 0.5 to the previous row and so on.

In:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Out:

```
1
0.5
0.25
0.125
```

I tried the following but does not work the right way. It is not cumulative and let's say perpetual.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.zeros(x.shape)

y[0] = 1
yd = pd.DataFrame(y)

k =  yd.shift(1) * 0.5

print (k)
```

Any idea? Thank you

---

2nd more complexed question based on previous issue.

```
data['y'] = np.where((data['a']<50) & (data['b']>0), data['initial'], pd.Series(0.99, data['y'].index).cumprod() / 0.99)
```

I tried this code but does not work. If the premises are true then call the 'initial' otherwise proceed to the cumulative multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`numpy.power`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

```
np.power(.5, x - 1)

       0
0  1.000
1  0.500
2  0.250
3  0.125
```

---

Or as [@DSM pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319772/python-pandas-cumulative-multiplication/52319816#comment91586959_52319816) (more intuitively)

```
.5 ** (x - 1)

       0
0  1.000
1  0.500
2  0.250
3  0.125
```

---

On the other hand, if you just want strictly successive powers of `.5`

```
.5 ** pd.Series(range(len(x)))

0    1.000
1    0.500
2    0.250
3    0.125
dtype: float64
```

Another alternative with `cumprod`

```
pd.Series(.5, x.index).cumprod() / .5

0    1.000
1    0.500
2    0.250
3    0.125
dtype: float64
```

Or

```
pd.Series({**dict.fromkeys(range(4), .5), **{0: 1}}).cumprod()

0    1.000
1    0.500
2    0.250
3    0.125
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why not just .5**(x-1)?

Comment: is there any way to do it using yd instead of x?

Comment: `yd` is a bunch of ones.  You want successive powers of `.5`

Comment: actually forget about x. I put it there just to form y. I need a column let's say 4x1, 1st element equals 1 and the rest three elements 0.5 of the previous one.

Comment: @user3203275: umm, there's only 1 such column, and it's the one this generates.  If you want to avoid any materialized `x`,  just use piRS's `.5 ** (pd.Series(range(len(x))`, but put in 4 for len(x), e.g. `.5 ** pd.Series(range(4))`.

Comment: could you please explain me a little bit the structure of the first cumprod approach? it looks interesting

Comment: @user3203275 I encourage you to play around with it.  I would usually delve into an explanation but this is a very simple snippet.  It would server you to take the first part `pd.Series(.5, x.index)` and see what you get.  Then add the `cumprod` and see what you get.  Then divide by `.5` and see what you get.  I say this to benefit you.  Typing this comment is likely more effort than typing an explanation but I believe you will be better off.

Comment: you are right, already I did it and I understood the structure. Of course, it takes time to have the full ownership. thanks a lot!

Comment: My inquiry, unfortunately, changed to a more complexed one... 

data['y'] = np.where((data['a']<50) & (data['b']>0), data['initial'], pd.Series(0.99, data['y'].index).cumprod() / 0.99)

I am not sure if it is ok to post it here. Let me edit the post once again.